# Imagemagick + Photoshop = image localization in web app

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop

I have just read [Automate Photoshop to insert text from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700792/automate-photoshop-to-insert-text-from-file#answer-772706) and I am wondering if I can define the text inside a PSD from a shell script. The problem I want to solve is that I don't want to have to bother my webdesigner everytime I need change a comma for a banner in my web app.

I am trying to bring together the following ideas:

1) Photoshop can load external variables to customize a PSD (see link above) -> great start;

2) Imagemagick can convert PSD to, say, JPG.

Result: I end up with a script called 'psd2jpg' that works like this

```
$ psd2jpg banner.psd caption='marketing stuff' banner.jpg
```

Does anyone know how to do something like that?

Comment: I think that sounds clever.  Do you have any specific questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I think I found the answer in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918405/command-line-manipulation-of-photoshop-images).

It is called Photoshop scripting. I'll try it with Javascript, in order to avoid being tied to a specific system (VB for Windows, or Apple Script for Mac)